# In .NET can a class have virtual constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Can a class have virtual constructor??

If yes, why it is required?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

no, a class cannot have a virtual constructor.

It doesn't make sense to have a virtual constructor. The order in which objects are constructed in C# is by constructing derived classes first, so the derived constructor is always called since the class you want to call is well known at the time of construction.

The other thing is, if you actually type this code out, you can quickly see that it makes very little sense at all

If you had:

```
public class BaseClass 
{
    public virtual BaseClass()
    {
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class InheritedClass : BaseClass
{
    //overrides baseclass constructor but why would you do this given that the     
    //constructor is always going to be called anyway??
    public override InheritedClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding call the base constructor in derived class: wouldn't one chain to base as normal, e.g 'public override InheritedClass() : base()'.

Comment: @paul ruane: you're correct, but the point I was trying to make is that overriding the base class is redundant because you're either going to be explicit about it and reference it using base() or you're not and it'll get called when the object is constructed anyway so having a virtual constructor is pointless

Comment: It makes perfect sense to have virtual constructors. This is what the various builder patterns achieve in languages that don’t support it directly.

Comment: I do not agree with the order of execution of constructors, i.e. First Derived and then Base. In c# Base class constructor would always be called before Derived class constructor.

Comment: Vishal, you are correct. Initializers run from most derived class to base class and constructors run from Base class to the most derived class.

Comment: @Vishal (and @​MRG) To be clear, it depends on what you mean by "call" vs. "run." The constructor inheritance hierarchy is ***called*** in order from Derived to Base, but their respective code bodies ***execute*** ("run", as you say) in the reverse order, from Base to Derived.

Comment: (@MRG my previous comment intended for you as well...)

Answer (score 13):

A virtual method is by definition *a method which is dispatched based on runtime type analysis of the receiver, not the compile-time static type analysis of the receiver*.

A constructor is a method called when a new instance of a particular type is created.

Since the runtime type of a newly created object is *always the same* (*) as its compile-time type, there is no need for virtual constructors: the runtime dispatch would always choose the same method as the static dispatch, so why bother making a difference?

(*) This is not entirely true; there are scenarios involving COM interop in which the runtime type of a construction is not the compile-time type. Many things are weird in the world of legacy interop code.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly, but the classic Gang of Four pattern Factory Method achieves what would amount to a virtual constructor of sorts, by deferring instantiation to subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

No, how would it work?  All constructors in the hierarchy have to be called when you derive child classes from base classes.  Making a constructor virtual would imply otherwise.

Something that may be described as having virtual constructor like behaviour, is when you use the factory pattern.  Imagine this scenario:

```
class AnimalFactory
{
    virtual Animal CreateAnimal( return new Animal("Cow"); );
}
```

The default behaviour of this factory is to create cows.  But if we create a derived class:

```
class DogFactory : AnimnalFactory
{
    override Animal CreateAnimal( return new Animal("Dog"); );
}
```

We are now creating dogs.  Of course this is not a true virtual constructor (which is impossible), this is virtual construction.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring something virtual  means that it can be overridden by a sub-class of the current class. However the constructor is called when a class is instantiated. At that time you can not be creating a subclass of the class in question so there would never be any need to declare a constructor virtual.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the definitions of the word constructor and virtual we came to a logical conclusion that a constructor can't be virtual.

Comment: Really? In Delphi, virtual constructors are a common occurence to go along with CLASS REFRENCE TYPES ("CLASS OF <ClassType>"). A concept of which C-programmers have no knowledge :-). Yes - I know the question says C#, but the concept of virtual constructors are not a contradiction in terms in all languages :-).

Comment: You have right, about virtual constructors in Delphi but, this consequence from the language specification. You declare a method and state this will be a constructor. The method name is not related to the type that create what so ever. And this is the key to understand why generally concept of virtual constructor is not valid. You can declare a factory method and even override it. So the  way is turned around Delphi has virtual method that can be named constructors but it do not have structure that it is a constructor by itself like other C langauges does.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI when people are asking for virtual constructors a very good pattern to look into is [InversionOfControl](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?InversionOfControl)

In .NET we have a couple of IoC containers such as ObjectBuilder, Unity, MEF, Spring.NET. In Java (with risk of showing off my Java incompetence) there's Spring, Tapestry and many others.

IMHO IoC is what makes OO deliver on its promises.

Answer (score 0):

For a flexibility of construction an abstract factory can be used. Lets say we have:

```
class A {}
class B : A {}
```

with abstract construction:

```
class AbstractFactoryA
{
   abstract A Create();
}
 class AbstractFactoryB
{
   override A Create() //or B if language support covariant returns
   {
      ...
      var result = new B(args)
      ... 
      return result;
   }
}
```

and template construction:

```
class TemplateFactoryA
{
   TemplateCreate()
   {
      ...
      InternalCreate(args)
      ...
   }
   abstract InternalCreate();
}
```

Constructors execution works in the form of:

```
ctor()
{
   base.ctor()
   ...
}
```

but with exact class.

Is there an language that support abstract factory pattern hidden in syntax sugar. It can be very useful. At the end ctor is a method :)