# Why can't serialization callback methods be virtual?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

I have a deserialization method (decorated with the `[OnDeserialized()]` attribute) which I want to override in a derived class. When I try to do so, I get the following runtime error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException'....
>   Type 'BaseObj' in assembly ... has method 'OnDeserialization' which is either static, virtual, abstract or generic, but is marked as being a serialization callback method.

I couldn't find any documentation confirming this restriction on serialization callbacks (other than the error message itself). Can anyone explain this strange limitation?

Based on a suggestion in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13664132/93394), I resorted to calling a separate virtual function from the OnDeserialization method, like so:

```
[Serializable()]
public class BaseObj
{   
    protected string obj { get; set; } 

    [OnDeserialized()]
    public void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
        //call the virtual method because deserialization callbacks can’t be virtual
        onDeserialized(context);
    }    
    virtual protected void onDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        obj = "This value was deserialized by the base class.";
    }   
}
[Serializable()]
public class DerivedObj : BaseObj
{    
    override protected void onDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        obj = "This value was deserialized by the derived class.";
    }    
}
```

This seems to work fine, but it seems rather "kludgey". Is this really my only option? Why can't a serialization callback method be virtual?

Comment: A mere guess: The method will be called via reflection based upon its `MethodInfo`. Whichever code is used to discover the `MethodInfo` in the first place might, for some reason, not discover the most specialized version of the method, but also does not go through the trouble of looking for it oneself. When invoking the method via its `MethodInfo`, the call will not be evaluated in a polymorphic way, which may result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I don't know why its there but when I looked into the source of json.net I found the following [code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/bbbddf0031fdced348b08d2435eb2d4698f50ef3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L1264). `if (method.IsVirtual) { throw new JsonException("Virtual Method '{0}' of type '{1}' cannot be marked with '{2}' attribute.".FormatWith(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, method, GetClrTypeFullName(method.DeclaringType), attributeType)); }`. The code is in the `IsValidCallback` method which is called from `GetCallbackMethodsForType`.

Comment: @NtFreX Good spot with the code, unfortunately the original commit of that line doesn't explain the reason for it. I'm inclinded to agree with O.R.Mapper here

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, your guess makes sense the more I think about it. I suppose json.net would have to add support for some sort of Attribute functionality like `[OnDeserialized(): Virtual]` to indicate the polymorphism to the serialization engine.

Comment: @kmote: I don't think `[OnDeserialized(): Virtual]` is valid C# syntax, is it? Anyway, if my guess is true, JSON.NET would have to check other `MethodInfo` objects to find out whether anything overrides the attributed method. The author(s) may have decided it's not worth the effort.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: no, my suggested attribute is definitely not valid syntax. I've seen similar extended attributes before, however (such as [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributeusageattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)), and was guessing that JSON.NET might be able to do something similar with their attributes to if they were going to support it. But, I agree that it is probably not worth the effort.

Comment: Firstly, it's not Json.NET throwing the exception; the **.Net runtime itself** is throwing the exception from the static constructor for `BaseObj`, which indicates that the type itself is invalid.  As to why this is, I can only guess it's for security reasons: calls to a a `virtual` serialization callback for a fully trusted type could be overridden blocked by a partially trusted derived type.  This is, I believe, why `ISerializable` is not available in partial trust: derived types could examine or modify the base type serialization process.

Answer (score 3):

I am facing same issue, and I saw this question. So I did some test, and I got some interesting findings, and I think I figured out why virtual is not needed from a different angle.
Here is my test.

```
[DataContract]
class Base
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    //cannot be virtual
    protected void OnDeserializedBase()
    {
        //base deserialization
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Derived : Base
{
    [OnDeserialized]
    //cannot be virtual
    OnDeserializedDerived()
    {
        //Derived deserialization
    }
}

Base b = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Derived)).ReadObject(stream);
```

What I find is, both OnDeserializedBase and OnDeserializedDerived will be invoked, in turns. Even if there is NO OnDeserialized in the derived class, **Base class's OnDeserializedBase will still be invoked**.

If that is the case, it makes no benefit from making this method virtual. Because, to get the benefit of a virtual method, you need to pass a derived object into base object, and call that base.virtualMethod(). There is never a chance to do it that way. But, you don't need to worry about losing the OnDeserialized functionality even you deserialize a derived class.

So after the test, I am happly to do the way that I posted.

Answer (score 2):

Since `BinaryFormatter` and `DataContractSerializer` don't call constructors when deserializing, `OnDeserializedAttribute` allows performing of operations you would normally do in a constructor, e.g. state initialization. Methods marked by this attribute are also executed in the same order constructors are: base first, then derived.

So for the purposes of deserialization you can treat those methods as constructors.

And virtual constructors [are not allowed in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651354/in-net-can-a-class-have-virtual-constructor).